# Crash in Cronet on Android [CronetDynamite.apk] SIGTRAP

Tags: android, crash, cronet

I use Cronet in my Android app.
Recently the following crash is reported in the Play Console (about 1 in 100 users is affected):

> [CronetDynamite.apk]
>
> SIGTRAP

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 14389 >>> scadica.aq <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x00000000003016c0  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000011/CronetDynamite.apk
```

I did not occur on my test devices.

I have just reported it to the  Chromium Issue Tracker.

The only similar report here seems to be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022413/strange-crash-in-cronetdynamite-apk-offset-0x1000-android).